# MySQL loop or nested query

Tags: php, mysql, loops, nested

Say I have a table friends

```
user_1  |  user_2
```

Then, say I want to see what these friends have been up to, so I check the posts table and updates table

```
post_id  | post_title | post_message |  user_id | timestamp

update_id | title | userid | timestamp
```

I want to achieve logic like the following : Get list of friends, go through this list of generated friends to see if they have added anything, sorted by the most recent activities first (timestamp).

```
Select user_1 from friends where user_2 = '$my_userid'
union
Select user_2 from friends where user_1 = '$my_userid'

//now loop through each of these friends and check the update/post tables to see if they have added anything recently
```

Can I do this all through 1 MySQL query, or do I have to break it up and use PHP?

Comment: @AshwinMukhija first I generated a list of friends. Then in PHP I looped through them and did individual queries for their activities, but since it's not selecting them all at once, the result only put the events in order (timestamp) per user, not overall.

Answer (score 1):

post_id  | post_title | post_message |  user_id | timestamp - Table_A

update_id | title | userid | timestamp - Table_B

Try the below query

```
SELECT A.*, B.* FROM Table_A AS A JOIN Table_B AS B ON B.userid = A.user_id
WHERE A.user_id IN (100,101,102) 
ORDER BY B.timestamp DESC;
```

A.* - will get you all the columns from the table A. If you want specific column `A.post_id`.

You can number of results by adding a LIMIT clause.

Note : I assume 100,101,102 are the user ids generated. You can add the user ids within the IN Clause.

**Update**

Put the user ids you need in the IN clause if you want to limit the friends. if not remove the where clause, so you can get the updates of all the friends without a limitation. You can order by any column you need. You can do ORDER BY A.user_id , A.post_id, Even multiple columns are possible

Comment: So I can just change the IN clause to be a nested query for a list of my friends?

Comment: that depends on your requirement. put the user ids you need in the IN clause if you want to limit the friends. if not remove the where clause, so you can get the updates of all the friends without a limitation.

Comment: Yes you can write a sub query in the IN clause

Comment: how does this treat ordering (timestamp) of values in table A since it's ordered by table B?

Comment: You can order by any column you need. You can do ORDER BY A.user_id , A.post_id, Even multiple columns are possible

Comment: I just found a bit of a problem with the query. It will only return values assuming they have both created an update AND a post. So, if the user has only created a post  it won't return anything.

Comment: Check the whether the user ids are matched

Comment: that's the problem. It will only return values if the userid appears in both tables. If the user only creates a post (and no update), nothing will be returned.